# Trim each line in a text file using php file functions

Tags: php, fopen

I have a text file having 10 lines and 50 characters in each line . I want to keep first 10 characters and delete remaining characters in each line. I used the following code

```
<?php
$target_file = 'test.txt';

$handle = fopen($target_file, "r");
if ($handle) {

while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
 $new_line=substr($line,0,10)."\n";
 $new_handle=fopen('test.knt',"a");
fwrite($new_handle,$new_line);

}
} 
fclose($new_handle);
?>
```

But the output file contains single line of 100 characters. New line character is not working. Any clues?

Comment: It should. Maybe your editor prefers "\r\n" instead of "\n" as new line. BTW you should move `$new_handle=fopen('test.knt',"a");` out of the loop.

Comment: Just use `EOL` instead of `\r\n` as it's operating system insensitive

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch you are right it is working now. Thanks

Comment: @Ohgodwhy please specify the syntax

Comment: Try using `.EOL` as opposed to `\n`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy True, however there is no warranty that the file to be read is encoded using the operating system default new line control character. Eg. a Linux file on Windows can be encoded using `\n`.

Comment: Check file permissions for test.txt , I tried your code, it worked after given 777 permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newline each OS

- "\r\n" : new line for Windows
- "\n" : new line for UNIX / Linux / MacOS 10.8+
- "\r" : new line for Old MacOS

Please see code / syntax below

```
<?php
$target_file = 'test.txt';
$new_target_file = 'test.knt';

$handle = fopen($target_file, "r");
$new_handle = fopen($new_target_file, "a"); // or use "w" instead "a" if you want to overwrite file everytime
if ($handle && $new_handle) {

    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $new_line=substr($line,0,10) . "\r\n";
        fwrite($new_handle,$new_line);
    }
    fclose($new_handle);
    fclose($handle);
}
```